# Сортировка по году в списке с LocalDateTime

Tags: java

Есть на входе не сортированный по дате список

```
List<UserMeal> mealList = Arrays.asList(new UserMeal(LocalDateTime.of(2015, Month.MAY, 30, 10, 0), "Завтрак", 500), ...);
```

Как оптимально взять из списка все значения, соответствующие одному году?

Comment: `mealList.get()` не работает?

Comment: год для каждого индекса списка конечно можно взять mealList.get(index).getDateTime().getYear()

Comment: есть какой-нибудь компактный способ из схожих списков получать подсписки разделенные или отсортированные по году/ам?

Comment: привет Topjava =)

Comment: `stream -> filter -> collect`. С сортировкой то же самое. Посмотрите в сторону `Stream API`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

взять из списка все значения, соответствующие одному году можно например так:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import java.util.function.*;

public class UserMealFilter {
    //для отфильтрованного списка
    private List<UserMeal> filteredMeal = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<UserMeal> filterByYear(List<UserMeal> inputList, int targetYear) {
        //получаем стрим из List
        Stream<UserMeal> mealListStream = inputList.stream();
        //лямбда для фильтрации
        Predicate<UserMeal> filter = userMeal -> userMeal.getDateTime().getYear()==targetYear;
        //лямбда для сохранения
        Consumer<UserMeal> consumer = userMeal -> filteredMeal.add(userMeal);
        //сама фильтрация
        mealListStream.filter(filter)
                      .forEach(consumer);
        return filteredMeal;
    }
}
```

Вызывать так

```
UserMealFilter userMealFilter = new UserMealFilter();
List<UserMeal> filteredMeal = userMealFilter.filterByYear(mealList, 2015);
```

А если вам сортировать надо, то это совсем другая история (смотрите интерфейс Comparator и Comparable)